# FileSystemWatcher files in subdirectory

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I'm trying to be notified if a file is created, copied, or moved into a directory i'm watching.
I only want to be notified about the files though, not the directories.

Here's some of the code I currently have:

```
_watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName;
_watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(file_created);
_watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(file_created);
_watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(file_created);
_watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
_watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Problem is, if I move a directory that contains a file in it, I get no event for that file.

How can I get it to notify me for all files added (regardless of how) to the watched directory or it's sub directories?

Incase I didn't explain good enough... I have *WatchedDirectory*, and *Directory1*. *Directory1* contains *Hello.txt*. If I move *Directory1* into *WatchedDirectory*, I want to be notified for *Hello.txt*.

**EDIT:** I should note my OS is Windows 8. And I do get notification for copy/paste events, but not move events (drag and drop into the folder).

Comment: The [FileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.includesubdirectories.aspx) should do that.

Comment: For me,the above code works very fine.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici: Josh already included that line in his code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this workaround could come in handy (but I'd be careful about performance as it involves recursion):

```
private static void file_created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Created)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(e.FullPath))
        {
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(e.FullPath))
            {
                var eventArgs = new FileSystemEventArgs(
                    WatcherChangeTypes.Created,
                    Path.GetDirectoryName(file),
                    Path.GetFileName(file));
                file_created(sender, eventArgs);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} created.",e.FullPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what is going on in this code from a summarized/top layer view?

Comment: Why do you need the recursive call?

Answer (score 4):

Add some more filters to your `NotifyFilters`. At the moment you're only watching for changes in file names. That, together with your Changed and Renamed handlers should do the job.

```
_watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
```

This seems to be working only for copy/paste actions. For cut/paste actions (or drag&drop), add the following notify filter too: `NotifyFilters.DirectoryName`.

**EDIT**

I've played around with it a bit more and indeed only one notification for the top level folder comes in. 
Makes sense, if you come to think of it. Since the change type is *created* then you know for sure that all files and folders inside it are new and you can process them.

So, @AlexFilipovici's approach is the only viable one, although I'd enqueue the result (folder) and process it on a worker thread (or task, whatever). You don't want to spend too much time inside a FSWatcher event handler, especially if files are coming in at a high rate.

Comment: I tried that but i'm still not getting notification for move events.

Comment: @Josh: Updated answer. Also tested it on Win 8 and works fine.

Comment: The *NotifyFilters.DirectoryName* filter fires an event for the directory, but not the contents (what I'm trying to get notified for).

Answer (score 1):

### Copying and moving folders

The operating system and FileSystemWatcher object interpret a cut-and-paste action or a move action as a **rename** action for a folder and its contents. If you cut and paste a folder with files into a folder being watched, the FileSystemWatcher object reports only the folder as new, but not its contents because they are essentially only renamed.

Reference: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

Comment: But I've set the *IncludeSubdirectories* property, and I'm monitoring for renamed events. Still no events are popping up.