# create folder firing two times

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, mvvm

My app two way sync app when iam created new folder from desktop it is some time creating extra folder with name "New folder "

private void FileSystemWatcherCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var parentDirectory = Directory.GetParent(e.FullPath).FullName;

```
                if (!this.IsWatchedObject(e.FullPath))
                {
                    return;
                }

                if (!this.IsFileOrDirectoryExists(e.FullPath))
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.FullPath))
                    {
                        this.Debug("FileSystemWatcherCreated", "Delete '{0}' from the icon overlay system...", e.FullPath);
                        var success = CloudFuzeIconOverlayAssystent.DeleteFileFolderRecord(e.FullPath, true, this.LogService);
                        this.Debug("FileSystemWatcherCreated", success.BooleanToSuccessFailLogString());
                        this.SendFileSystemItemChangedRecursively(e.FullPath);
                    }

                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Directory.Exists(e.FullPath))
                    { //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301598/filesystemwatcher-files-in-subdirectory
                        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(e.FullPath))
                        {
                            var eventArgs = new FileSystemEventArgs(
                                WatcherChangeTypes.Created,
                                Path.GetDirectoryName(file),
                                Path.GetFileName(file));
                            FileSystemWatcherCreated(sender, eventArgs);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (this.IsFileFolderAddedToRootFolder(this.cloudFuzeDirectory, e.FullPath))
                {
                    return;
                }

                if (this.cloudFuzeDirectory == parentDirectory)
                {
                    return;
                }

                var type = Directory.Exists(e.FullPath) ? WellKnownFileFoderTypes.Folder : WellKnownFileFoderTypes.File;

                this.Debug("FileSystemWatcherCreated", "Add '{0}' in the queue for registration in the local storage...", e.FullPath);
                this.addedFileFolders.Enqueue(new FileFolder
                {
                    SavedFilePath = e.FullPath,
                    FileType = type,
                    Type = type
                });


        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            this.Error("FileSystemWatcherCreated", exc);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Okay. What is the question? What errors do you get? Where does the problem occur? Explain, please.

Comment: when we create folder from windows exprl it is firing two folders some times added extra folder with name "New folder"

Comment: Sorry, I asked that wrong. _Edit your question to explain, please. Your question does not contain a question_.

Comment: You should also format pasted code properly.

Comment: my problem is when iam created new folder it is taking name as "New folder " then after changing the name it is to some "ABC " it is creting new folder and ABC also

Comment: iam filtered events also likeIncludeSubdirectories = true,
                InternalBufferSize = 8192,/*65536,*/
                NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.Attributes | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size | NotifyFilters.FileName |NotifyFilters.CreationTime |NotifyFilters.Security  ,